# How to handle "invalid use of non-static data member" in class Implementation in c++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, trie

I've been trying to solve a question Word Search II on LeetCode that requires use of Trie to help make the backtracking calls more efficient and basically tries are to be used, I've been trying to implement my own trie class but I'm running into a road block in my `remove` function, it requires a copy of root, but I'm not sure how to give it one. Here is the part I'm having trouble with:

> `TrieNode* crawl = root` in the function `remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl = root, int depth = 0)`
>
> The error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Trie::root'
>
> I don't know the correct way to do it.

```
TrieNode* remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl = root, int depth = 0) { 
    if(!crawl) return nullptr; 

    if(depth == word.size()) { 
        if(crawl->isLeaf) crawl->isLeaf = false; 
        if(isEmpty(crawl)) { 
            delete crawl; 
            crawl = nullptr; 
        } 
        return crawl; 
    }

    int index = word[depth] - 'a';            
    crawl->arr[index] = remove(word, crawl->arr[index], depth + 1); 

    if(isEmpty(crawl) && crawl->isLeaf == false) { 
        delete crawl; 
        crawl = nullptr; 
    } 

    return crawl; 
}
```

This is what my Trie class looks like:

```
class Trie {
    private:
        TrieNode* root;

    public:            
        Trie() : root(new TrieNode()) {};
    
        void insert(const string &word) {
            auto crawl = root;
            // does it's thing
        }

        bool search(const string &word) {
            auto crawl = root;
            // does it's thing
        }
    
        bool isPrefix(const string &word) {
            auto crawl = root;
            // does it's thing
        }
    

        bool isEmpty(TrieNode* root) { 
            for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) if(root->arr[i]) return false; 
            return true; 
        } 
        
        TrieNode* remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl = root, int depth = 0) {
```

With this as the TrieNode:

```
struct TrieNode {
    bool isLeaf;
    vector<TrieNode*> arr;
    TrieNode() : isLeaf(false), arr(26, nullptr) {};
};
```

Edit: Special thanks to @SPD for suggesting an improvement on the remove function

Comment: You cannot refer to the non static member variable `root` in the function's parameter like `TrieNode* crawl = root`.

Comment: `delete` isn’t a function, don’t put parentheses around its argument (same as for `return`!).

Comment: You don't need to pass the parent pointer (i.e. crawl) in remove(), this can be done when you unwind the recursive call stack

Comment: @SPD I'm not sure I understand, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @gh05t, I elaborated my comments as an answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate to @darune's answer would be to have an overload:

```
TrieNode* remove(const string& word)
{
    return remove(word, root);
}
TrieNode* remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl, int depth = 0) { 
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use member variables as default arguments.

*However instead of:*

```
TrieNode* remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl = root, int depth = 0) { 
//...
```

*You could do*

```
TrieNode* remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl = nullptr, int depth = 0) { 
  if (!crawl) {
    crawl = root;
  }
  //...
```

Comment: But the function is recursive in nature with null being a base case, I wasn't sure if that would mess up with the function calls, that's why I didn't do it that way. I think it will go in an infinite loop if I do it like this.

Comment: @gh05t I just showed you to avoid the error. Why do you think that ? (it doesn't look like that)

Comment: Okay yes you're right the depth == word.size() prevents it from going to the next step which would've made it infinite otherwise, is this the proper way to deal with this issue or could've I structured my struct and class better somehow? I'm waiting for someone to answer along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. you don't really need a Trie class, TrieNode is sufficient. All operations insert/remove can be moved to TrieNode, you'll probably find it more 'natural' to write member functions of TrieNode
2. If you stick to you existing design and delete crawl itself followed by `crawl = nullptr`, I think you need to pass crawl by pointer reference rather than just pointer.
3. An alternative to #2 is to delete crawl in the calling stack. remove() now returns a boolean indicating if the caller can safely delete this node. Sample code below.
4. Lastly, please consider using managed ptrs rather than raw ptrs. (It probably doesn't matter for a leetcode exercise)

```
bool remove(string word, TrieNode* crawl, int depth = 0) { 
    if(!crawl) return true; 

    if(depth == word.size()) { 
        if(crawl->isLeaf) crawl->isLeaf = false; 
        return isEmpty(crawl);
    }

    int index = word[depth] - 'a';
    if (remove(word, crawl->arr[index], depth + 1)) {
        // it's empty or nullptr, safe to remove
        delete crawl->arr[index];
        crawl->arr[index] = nullptr; 
    }
    return !crawl->isLeaf && isEmpty(crawl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one little thing, I tried to use this version and if I add words "babaa" and "baci", after removing "baci", it still has the word "bac" (not as a word but a prefix at least) in it, so it just removed the 'i' not 'c' and 'i' like it ideally should.

Comment: @gh05t I think the returning condition should be ```return !crawl->isLeaf() && isEmpty(crawl);```. I missed the '!'. Given it a try ;)

Comment: Yes that was the issue!